WordPress Plugin translation not working EN to FR, what's the reason?
I'm creating a new plugin. I generated the PO and MO files for my plugin using POedit and I followed all the steps as described on https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/, from writing a perfect header in the main plugin file till adding php code in the same file in order to load text domain and the MO file.
When I change the site language from English to French the plugin still displaying EN strings.
What could be the issue? Is it because the plugin is not on wordpress.org yet?
Here's my laptop config :
locahost : wampserver
Windows 10
Php version : 8.1

Thanks in advance!
Note:
In the main plugin file, in order to load the PO and MO files, I put this :
/**
 * wpdocs_load_textdomain() loads Text Domain for the translation
 */
function wpdocs_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'str-sticky-header', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang' ); 
}


/**
 * my_plugin_load_my_own_textdomain( $mofile, $domain )  loads the MO file for the translation
 * @param $mofile
 * @param $domain
 */
function my_plugin_load_my_own_textdomain( $mofile, $domain ) {
    if ( 'str-sticky-header' === $domain && false !== strpos( $mofile, WP_LANG_DIR . '/plugins/' ) ) {
        $locale = apply_filters( 'plugin_locale', determine_locale(), $domain );
        $mofile = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang/' . $domain . '-' . $locale . '.mo';
    }
    die($mofile);
    return $mofile;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpdocs_load_textdomain' );
add_filter( 'load_textdomain_mofile', 'my_plugin_load_my_own_textdomain', 10, 2 );

The die($mofile) function is displaying the right MO file. Is the error in the translation itself?

How are you displaying the strings in your plugin?

a lot of times, inside the php file that I want to translate, I use the Gettext functions, like this one :        <?php printf( esc_html__( /* translators: Name: The name of a variable (which is Z-index). */ '%s value is set up to 100', 'str-sticky-header' ), 'Z-index' ); ?>

Here's the solution :
I'm talking about my case here,
When I added the Text Domain Name to Gettext functions in interface.php file, I used this command line :
php add-textdomain.php TextDomainNameOfThePlugin PathToInterfaceFile/interface.php > tdn.php ,
So I generated tdn.php as you can see in that command line, and constructed my POT, PO and MO files based on this UNUSED NEW FILE, and I forgot to either rename tdn.php to interface.php (and delete the old interface.php) so I can use it, or to copy its content and paste in into interface.php file that didn't contain Text Domain Name in its Gettext functions.
So now, I just copied tdn.php content to interface.php, and the translation works perfectly.
Thanks @DanieleAlessandra !

all the code you shared with us is correct. You do not even need the function my_plugin_load_my_own_textdomain but I assume that it is used for debugging only.
The problem should be in a part of your code that we do not see. If well configured, translations must work on your local environment, even if the plugin is not yet distributed.
Check the following things:

Does your .mo file exist? You said that when you execute die($mofile) you see something that looks like the right file, please check twice with something like is_file($mofile). If the file is missing, in fact, translation fails silently.
Is the name correct? Your .mo file must be named like this <text_domain>-<locale>.mo, in your case the file must be named str-sticky-header-fr_FR.mo. This should be already this way, because you are seeing the name in my_plugin_load_my_own_textdomain
Is your file valid? It may be corrupted, what are you using to generate translatio files? Try this online free resource https://localise.biz/free/poeditor (not mine, I googled it).

While trying to figure out your issue, I wrote a simple PHP script that - once placed in a directory along your .mo translations - checks if they work. Hopefully this script could help you and other people investigating similar issues. You may find it here: https://github.com/DanieleAlessandra/wp-translation-check

[Edit: adding a snippet to investigate translation loading state]
After several attempts we still don't know if your translation file has being loaded. Please add the following snippet anywhere to have an output of loaded strings for the current language in your text domain:
$translations = get_translations_for_domain( 'str-sticky-header' );
echo('<pre>');
var_dump($translations->entries);

The perfect place to put this snippet is immediatelu after a failed translation, so you can have the un-translated string in front of your eyes along with this snippet output.
The output should be something similar to the following:
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Translation_Entry)#2914 (9) {
    ["is_plural"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["context"]=>
    NULL
    ["singular"]=>
    string(36) "Hello, this is the original message!"
    ["plural"]=>
    NULL
    ["translations"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(43) "Bonjour, ceci est un message en français!"
    }
    ["translator_comments"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["extracted_comments"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["references"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["flags"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}

Hopefully you will have more entries.
With this output you will be able to undestand what is happening:

The output is an empty Array? Your file is not being loaded or there is a typo in textdomain string.

Check textdomain.
Check file name.


The output is full of translations? Maybe this translation is missing your strings, or you are not using this translation.

Check textdomain in your code, inside any __(), _e(), or any other translation, you may have a typo there.
Check strings, they must be identical to translation keys, spaces counts and it's case sensitive.


After cheching 1 and 2 still no success: you could have some cache in place.

Remove any cache plugin.
Purge cache if possible.



Please keep me posted with results.

Okey, thanks for that, now, I re-tested a bunch of times, and I added die('TXT DOMAIN : ' . $domain . ' , MO FILE : ' . $mofile );  after if condition and before the return command :  and it gave me as a result TXT DOMAIN : ultimate-addons-for-gutenberg , MO FILE : C:\wamp64\www\webtips\smoothies/wp-content/languages/plugins/ultimate-addons-for-gutenberg-fr_FR.mo which surprised me because I've tested it before, and it gave me the good files, now it is giving something completly new

That's not your plugin. Using diefor debugging purpose is wrong. Your code stops working before even loading your plugin, if you disable ultimate-addons-for-gutenberg you'll see the next one, and so on.

Okey, I understand that, but I have a question though, where should I put the MO and PO files ? because I put them inside my plugin's repository => C:\wamp64\www\webtips\smoothies/wp-content/plugins/str-sticky-header/lang/

Here's what I've done @DanieleAlessandra, I removed the die() command from that function, and I added another function echo '1 . TXT DOMAIN : ' . $domain . ' , MO FILE : ' . $mofile . '<br><br>'; inside the if() condition, and I added the same echo() but just changing the number 1 to 2 after the if() condition. The result was as you mentioned it, I had other plugin internationalization files, then the last one is the correct one, but it still not working ...

I tried to generate a new MO file using the link you gave to me link , and it still not working

I added another snippet to the answer, please use the snippet to see if your translation is being loaded then let me know what you discovered.

Finally, I found the bug, it was so stupid to be honest, the problem was when I added the Text Domain Name to Gettext functions, I used a command line using GIT, so I generated a new file with that command line, and constructed my POT, PO and MO files based on this UNUSED NEW FILE,  I forgot to either rename that new file so I can use it or to copy its content and paste in into the file that didn't contain Text Domain Name in its Gettext functions, thank you so much for your help @DanieleAlessandra

Can I talk to you about another issue that I have, or should I open a new ticket for that ?

:D StackOverflow is not a ticket portal, it's a community sharing knowledge. It's better for everyone to have separated questions for different issues.
